# CI : You did not select a file to upload. error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

okay, this is my controller :

```
public function buktisaldo(){
//load library
$this->load->library('upload');
//Set the config
$config['upload_path'] = "./assets/images/campaigner/";
$config['allowed_types'] = "*";
//Initialize
$this->upload->initialize($config);
//Upload file
if( !$this->upload->do_upload("bukti")){
    //echo the errors
    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}
    $data = array(
        'bukti' => $this->upload->file_name
        );
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $this->db->where('id_user',$id);
    $this->db->where('status','Sedang Diproses');
    $this->db->update('saldo',$data);
    $this->load->view('v_atas',$data);
    $this->load->view('e_konfirmasisaldo',$data);
    $this->load->view('v_bawah',$data);
    }
```

and this is my view :

```
<?php echo form_open('member/buktisaldo');?>
<input type="file" name="bukti">
<input type="submit" value="send">
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

and when i run this code, it shows error "You did not select a file to upload."

this is `var_dump()` script :

```
UPDATE `saldo` SET `bukti` = '' WHERE `id_user` = '74' AND `status` = 'Sedang Diproses'
```

it seems like my input name is wrong, but its correct, how to fix that ?

Comment: I think your using Codeignitor then Try   form_open_multipart()

    This function is absolutely identical to the form_open() tag above except that it adds a multipart attribute, which is necessary if you would like to use the form to upload files with.

Comment: yes, thanks it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Controller :**

**Change This**

```
   $file_name = $this->upload->data('file_name'); 
   $data = array('bukti' => $file_name);
```

**In View :**

form should be like this  :

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('member/buktisaldo');?>
```

Comment: thanks it works. i just need to chage form_open to form_open_multipart :)